# Search for "pinhole" SMT switch (like "reset" switch operated with paperclip)

Tags: stm32, reset

I search for a small switch, momentary on, SMT mounting type, I can put on my STM32 board for entering DFU. I search for a small switch with only a small hole to put a pin or a paperclip.
I thing I don't get the right name of this kind of switch to search. Can someone can tell me the name or have an entry point?

EDIT:
[image: pinhole switch]

Comment: Typically the switch in such a case is ordinary, it is the hole in the product housing which is small.  Your problem is that you don't yet have a housing.  Also part selection questions are off topic here.

Comment: Usually push button SMT switches are used on most products, the hole is provided by a plastic injection molded case. Find a router or other device with a button, open it up and see how they did it.

Answer (score 6):

All the devices I've opened that had a "paperclip pinhole reset" had a hole in the enclosure and a standard pcb switch like this one behind it.

[image]

If you don't have an enclosure (just a PCB) you can't do that, but you could use a [reverse-mounted switch](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/e-switch/RT1105AF160Q/EG5982-ND/3778152) with a hole in the PCB instead...

[image]

This is a pretty uncommon and hard to find component though.

Comment: The reverse switch is a good idea. Thanks to take time to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Most devices use a [right angle toggle switch](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/switches/tactile-switches/197?k=momentary%20tactile%20push%20button%20right%20angle%20smt&k=&pkeyword=momentary%20tactile%20push%20button%20right%20angle%20smt&sv=0&pv69=343110&pv69=409420&pv69=411921&sf=1&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=500) that is mounted to the PCB. Plastic injection molding from the case cover the switch and PCB from the user. You can make the hole as small as you want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit: After clarifying what you mean I am unsure something like that exists. What I personally would do in this case is use a 2 pin header instead, which you can short if you need a reset. Most users would not randomly do that I would guess.

Comment: I don't want user can easily push the button, I take a look on all Digikey, Mouser and Farnell catalog and don't find any suitable switch, that why I thing I user the wrong name...I edit my post to put picture of what I think it can look like.

Comment: Oh I see. Well, sadly I cannot help you with that as I have never seen anything like that, not sure it even exists. Usually how this is done is you use a normal tact switch and then make a tiny hole in the housing so it is only accessible with a paperclip or a needle of some sort.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I think this kind of device not exist, I will probably change my mind on how handle the reset and DFU access... Thank to take time for me

Comment: If you have access to a 3D printer, you could make a small box with a small hole in the top that you could glue over a normal switch to prevent accidental operation of the switch.